# How to change my Git workflow to include my new server

Tags: git, github

**The problem**

I've got a Git repo for my website, that is a local folder. I commit changes to the repo, then push to the master on git. Previously the site then updated (as it was hosted on Github).

So i usually commands such as:

```
git add .

git commit -m "my commit message"
```

and

```
git push origin master
```

Now that I've changed hosts, and I have my own server now, I'm struggling to work out how to include the new server into the equation.

**Confusion**

I've read about cloning and using hooks, although for a beginner who has never done much more outside a simple push/pull on a single repo, I'm slightly overwhelmed. What I need to know is, where to start. What's the best option for this type of workflow of including the remote server, git and my local repo?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have git running on your new server?  If not that would be your first step.  Start here to learn how to do that: http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-on-the-Server

Once that's done, you can push from your local to it:

```
git remote add mynewserver <remote-git-repo-address>
git push mynewserver master
```

And if you don't want to push to Github anymore:

`git remote rm origin`

Comment: Hi Matt, yes I have git on the server. May i ask, using `git remote add mynewserver <remote-git-repo-address> - is the remote address just where i want the clone to go on my server?

Comment: You need to create the repository on the server first.  Then the remote repo address will include the server name, possibly folder structure, and repository name.  This will vary depending on your protocol (http vs. ssh vs. git)